# StringBuffer not appending the string to webview

Tags: android, uiwebview, stringbuffer

i have string like this:

I have 2 shirts: //there is a line break here

(i) Red //there is a line break here

(ii) White //there is a line break here

i am trying to append this string uisng string buffer like this

```
html.append("<p>+string+</p>");
```

But i am getting entire content in one like like this

```
"I have 2 shirts (i) Red (ii) White"
```

why so? how can i make that to render how ever the string is?

EDIT :

i have the string in xml where enter is pressed whereever i have mentioned it has a line break

Answer (score 0):

If you display this text on web you should add `<br/>` tag in places where you want to break line.

Comment: @Goofy Instead of pressing enter, insert <br />